# Express parse content in body or query params

Tags: node.js, express

I have an endpoint that accepts json either in the URL or the message body (POST of course)

```
app.post('/book/addBooks', function (req, res) {
...
```

I know that the new book JSON coming from the server is going to either be a query param

```
<server>/book/addBooks?books=[{...},{...}]
```

or from the body

```
<server>/book/addBooks
```

body:

```
books=[{...},{...}]
```

Basically I am checking for both:

```
req.body.books
```

or

```
req.query.books
```

And picking the first one that has content.  Is there a better way to get at the 'books' in express?

Side note: before you trash the fact that you can pass in url or body I am writing a service that mimics another API, since the other API allows this junk I have to as well.

Comment: What do you mean by "better way to get at the books"?

Comment: http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.param

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From express docs

> req.param(name)
>
> Return the value of param name when present.
>
> // ?name=tobi req.param('name') // => "tobi"
>
> // POST name=tobi req.param('name') // => "tobi"
>
> // /user/tobi for /user/:name  req.param('name') // => "tobi"

Here is the lookup order:

> Lookup is performed in the following order:
>
> ```
> req.params
> req.body
> req.query
> ```

Comment: `req.param('name')` is now depricated.

Answer (score 0):

case use 
req.params : when is a rest value example

```
/users/:id
```

req.body :  when send data for method post
req.query : when send data for method get example

```
 /users?thisIsaVar=thisIsaValue
```

ok, expressjs the post method is body